# Align cylinder center with edge

Tags: vertices, edges, snapping, coordinates, transform-orientation

I've been trying to solve this problem for days now and i'm stuck. I want to align this cylinders center line with the selected line.

1. I tryed to use the location information/coordinates of the line end points on the cylinder but it did not work.
2. I tryed to use the snap tools but only got it align with pivot points, the cylinder did not take the transformation of the line.
   (the way i got these lines is by selecting two cube vertices and filling the diagonals in edit mode)
3. The second picture is just me "eyeballing" it.

Thanks!

[image: I want to align this cylinders center line with the selected line.]

[image: And this is how it should look like, aligned with cylinder center line.]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to align in object mode, without moving / re-orienting the cylinder's mesh with respect to its object origin...

A 'classic' approach to this is to parent the  object to a suitably-aligned Empty, and snap the Empty to the target. The Empty can be placed and aligned by numerous methods.. usually involving combinations of <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> 'Cursor to Selected', and 'Selection to Cursor', and Face-snapping with 'Align Rotation to Target' checked.

In this example, for speed, only vertex-snapping, with alignment,  is used. The top face of the cylinder has been [poked](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/face/poke_faces.html) to put a vertex at its centre (whose normal is the same as the original face)

[image]

..the empty is snapped to the vertex: the cylinder is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> parented to the Empty: the Empty is snapped to the ends of the lines.

When done, the Cylinder is <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> un-parented, with 'Keep Transform' selected.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if duplicated edge segment could be pulled on x or y while holding ctrl so that it gets dragged by a single unit of what snap option is set to make.

Then by separating it from the mesh as seperate object, and followed by applying skin modifier to hit Alt+C to make mesh out of it.
Then I guess ctrl+shift+c could centre the origin point.

Select end face of what skin mod has made after alt+c, then hit E to extrude to collapse with alt+m while the face is still selected.
It will give You a centred geometry point which You can ctrl+b,v from centre to extrude again and collapse with alt+m.

Just keep in mind subdivisions of geometry to make square as round by selecting geometry added after subdividing to scale it enough to make
round.

By the way I'm using only 2.79b so I am not sure if the shortcuts are the same in the one which you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...

Try setting your 3d cursor to the edge you have selected, then on the cylinder, select it, press "Shift + S", then "move object to active cursor". You might have to do some adjusting but that'll get you there.

If you can't move the cursor to the plane, you could subdivide and add a vertices in the middle that can be used.